# HTML: How to align left, center, and right footer phrases. Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, footer, styling

I'm having issues aligning my footer text in a straight line. I'm a beginner here so I apologize if this question is redundant! See below:

[image]

I need all three of those lines, to be in a straight line.

My professor teaches a grid method, but that's not working for me at the moment. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex"> 

<style>

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}
</style>
<title>Custom Error Page</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" style = "background-color: #d8edd0">
            <h1><center>Page Not Found</center></h1>
            <h3><center>Something went wrong!</center></h3>
        </div>

    <div class="card-body">     
        <img src = "images/404.png" alt = "404" style="width:50%;"/> 
        <p style="text-align:center;">Perhaps you would like to visit the following pages:</p>
        <a href="http://cisstudent.uma.edu/~student800/WebPortfolio_After_Class_12/WebPortfolio/portfolio.php"><p style="text-align:center">Web Portfolio</p></a>
        <a href="http://cisstudent.uma.edu/~student800/WebPortfolio_After_Class_12/WebPortfolio/index.php"><p style="text-align:center">Web Development Portfolio</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
    
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p style = "text-align: left;">&copy; KoKo Kreations</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="http://cisstudent.uma.edu/~student800/WebPortfolio_After_Class_12/WebPortfolio/sitemap.html"><p style="text-align:center">Sitemap</p></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p style = "text-align: right;"> Mary Newkirk </p>
        </div>  
        
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Come on, where are your references to Bootstrap files? It seems like you didn't reference/install Bootstrap for this HTML page. Here is the documentation for Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/. If you're a beginner, I will highly recommend you go through it.

Comment: I gave the answer. Was it so necessary for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.card .row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" style = "background-color: #d8edd0">
            <h1><center>Page Not Found</center></h1>
            <h3><center>Something went wrong!</center></h3>
        </div>

    <div class="card-body">     
        <img src = "images/404.png" alt = "404" style="width:50%;"/> 
        <p style="text-align:center;">Perhaps you would like to visit the following pages:</p>
        <a href="http://cisstudent.uma.edu/~student800/WebPortfolio_After_Class_12/WebPortfolio/portfolio.php"><p style="text-align:center">Web Portfolio</p></a>
        <a href="http://cisstudent.uma.edu/~student800/WebPortfolio_After_Class_12/WebPortfolio/index.php"><p style="text-align:center">Web Development Portfolio</p></a>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
    
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p style = "text-align: left;">&copy; KoKo Kreations</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="http://cisstudent.uma.edu/~student800/WebPortfolio_After_Class_12/WebPortfolio/sitemap.html"><p style="text-align:center">Sitemap</p></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p style = "text-align: right;"> Mary Newkirk </p>
        </div>  
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need such a result?